# Как в условии сравнить 2 строки с элементами словаря

Tags: c#

Есть словарь:

```
var AttributesDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string query7 = "SELECT Attribute1, Attribute2 FROM AttributesRules ";


SqlCommand cmd7 = new SqlCommand(query7, connection);
connection.Open();

SqlDataReader reader = cmd7.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    string strAttribute1 = reader[0].ToString();
    string strAttribute2 = reader[1].ToString();
    //char[] charsToTrim1 = { ' ', '-' };
    string strAttribute1_trim = PatchModelType(strAttribute1);
    string strAttribute2_trim = PatchModelType(strAttribute2);
    //Attribute1List.Add(strAttribute1_trim);
    //Attribute2List.Add(strAttribute2_trim);
    AttributesDict.Add(strAttribute1_trim, strAttribute2_trim);
}
```

Нужно дальше в условии сравнить 2 строки с элементами словаря, причём первую строку с первым полем словаря, а вторую со вторым

```
for (int i = 0; i < selectedDevices.Length; i++)

    string strSourceModelType = PatchModelType(selectedDevices[i].SerialNumber);
    if (String.Compare(strSourceModelType, strTargetModelType) != 0)
    {
        if (В ЭТОМ УСЛОВИИ СРАВНИТЬ, ЧТО НЕТ ПЕРЕСЕЧЕНИЙ С ЭЛЛЕМЕНТАМИ СЛОВАРЯ)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: Используйте AttributesDict.ContainsKey, а потом, если ключ найден, сравните value. Тут подробнее https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/how-to-find-a-key-in-a-dictionary-with-C-Sharp/

Comment: А на кой тут словарь? Имхо, должен быть список (LIst) и тип из двух свойств (или кортеж).

Comment: Или вообще проверку прямо в БД нужно делать. Зависит от размера `selectedDevices`.

Comment: Спасибо, сделал лист с tuple. Проблема решена